# How can we verify Products price and subtotal on cart page for an e-commerce website using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, e-commerce, price, subtotal

There are 3 products on cart page with product name, price ,quantity,subtotal columns.

We have added these products to the cart from Shop page where all products are visible.

Please help me how can we verify price and subtotal for each product here?

Using list webelements I got the product name and price values but how can I verify these with expected?
List rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='table table-striped cart-items']/tbody/tr"));
int count= rows.size();

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the list of values using a `for` loop and compare with expected data:

```
for(int i = 0, j=i+1; i<rows.size(); i++) { 
    Assert.assertEquals(rows.get(i).getText(), sheet.getRow(j).getCell(0).toString());
}
```